# How to pass build properties to dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net

In my C# and .net core program, I want to dynamically select dependency by using properties in the .csproj file. I learned from online that I can supply those properties while using the msbuild command. However, I am using dotnet. How then can I supply those flags?

Comment: Did you try something? Did you get errors? [Seems to be pretty straightforward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x), what happened when you tried?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I can see the confusion arises due to a misunderstanding of the relationship of msbuild and dotnet. dotnet is a wrapper of tools such as nuget and msbuild. As per the doc,

> the dotnet build command accepts MSBuild options, such as /p for
>   setting properties or /l to define a logger.

you can supply msbuild property like so:

```
dotnet build /p:property0=val0;property1=val1
```

Be careful though, if you are using this on linux or mac, when supplying multiple properties using ";", you should quote the entire /p flag.

Comment: Just a quick heads-up that this doesn't work for `dotnet run`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run#description